# Issue creating archive for submission to app store - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to archive my app and validate it and export to release to the App Store but I keep getting this error message:

> No software with CFBundleIdentifier of 'com.dev.Minty-Goat-Lawn-Care' exists.  Verify your bundle identifier is correct.  If it is, you may need to log into iTunes Connect to create the application.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app ID section of your developer portal you must put `com.dev.Minty-Goat-Lawn-Care` (This is what you have named it in your portal).

This applies to everything else you do. *Your bundle name must be consistent*:

1. Your project's identifier
2. your appID (in the portal)
3. the reverse domain name identifier you first set in iTunes connect.

You might have also named your identifier, `com.dev.Minty-Goat-Lawn-Care`, `com.dev.MintyGoatLawnCare`. Your identifier must be the **common** identifier between all three things listed above.

Comment: Where is my developer portal you are talking about?

Comment: developer.apple.com -> Member Center -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Identifiers -> App IDs

Comment: it seems to be correct for all of them.  I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Do your identifiers contain dashes? If yes, then your app in iTunesConnect might have a different identifier than your project (but you can't change the identifier in iTunesConnect, so you'll have to do that in your project)

Comment: How do i find that out?  I am simply releasing everything through xcode.  I went to archives to create a file to export it and than I went to the application loader to upload it.  That is when I get the error.

Comment: iTunesConnect -> My Apps -> *yourapp* -> More -> About this app -> Bundle ID

Comment: It is not released into the itunesconnect yet.  That is were I am going to release it to but I can't because of the error I am getting, but when I go to add app and go to bundler id it says:  Xcode iOS App ID com dev Minty-Goat-Lawn-Care - com.dev.Minty-Goat-Lawn-Care

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69052/discussion-between-nate-lee-and-david-biga).